# Unable to programmatically open input selector dialog in Angular

Tags: angular

I have an Angular app which has a stylized input box so I keep another actual  element which I call .click() on to open the dialog

This used to work great but for some reason stopped working recently? Anyway I can't make it work even though this all should be quite simple to do...

I've tried every way I can think to access my input and click it all to no avail

```
  <input type="file" id="fileInputRef">
  <button (click)="fileInputRef.click()">open</button>
```

this produces the error "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'click')"

```
  <input type="file" #fileInputRef>
  <button (click)="fileInputRef.click()">open</button>
```

this produces no effect at all, no error in console even

so I tried moving it to my component's code like so

```
  <input type="file" #fileInputRef>
  <button (click)="doClick()">open</button>
```

and in my typescript

```
  @ViewChild('fileInputRef') fileInputRef: HTMLInputElement;
  
  public doClick() {
    this.fileInputRef.click();
  }
```

but then this errors with "this.fileInputRef.click is not a function"

If I print out this.fileInputRef it looks like "ElementRef {nativeElement: input}"

So lastly I tried

```
  public doClick() {
    this.fileInputRef.nativeElement.click();
  }
```

which produces no effect

I'm not sure why this feature used to be working and stopped but I'm sure I'm missing something basic

How can I programmatically fire of a click for a file input element in my html

Comment: What are you doing with the file input? Know that certain browsers (Safari comes to mind) may disable elements that are hidden using `display: none`, meaning clicking on them does nothing...

Comment: it used to be hidden (and always worked in safari and chrome) but for this minimal test example I made sure to remove any styling or other elements - I just want to fire a click on the file input element so that the file picker dialog pops up

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ElementRef` to click file type from html. See below code implemented properly and it works fine.

```
<input type="file" (change)="handleFileInput($event.target.files)" #fileInput style="display:none" multiple>
<button type="button"(click)="fileInput.click()" > Open </button>

@ViewChild('fileInput') myFileInputVariable: ElementRef;
```

And when you want to reset input field.

```
this.myFileInputVariable.nativeElement.value = "";
```

Comment: Thanks Bharat, this was how I used to have it setup but it's not working. Clicking the Open button has no effect :-\

Comment: @JoshuaOhana You wrote HTMLInputElement, did you tried ElementRef instead?

Answer (score 0):

No idea what happened but this was resolved after I updated and restarted Chrome :-\ everything started to work again normally